# rails cancan i18n exception message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, cancan

I have followed [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Exception-Handling) to write exception handling for cancan.
First, I have a Product model in the "new" action
Here is the english locale file:

```
# in config/locales/en.yml
en:
  unauthorized:
    manage:
      all: "Not authorized to %{action} %{subject}."
```

The expected result is fine:

```
Not authorized to new Product.
```

But my question is now I have another locale ex: .de

```
# in config/locales/en.yml
de:
  unauthorized:
    manage:
      all: "Non autorisé à %{action} %{subject}."
```

Then I'll get

Non autorisé à new Product

What I want is

```
Non autorisé à nouveau produit.
```

Temporarily I have 2 options to achieve this,
One is I guess I could just modify the source code in cancan.
The second is append some translated text to it.
But is there something native way?

Thanks

Comment: did you accomplish this?

Comment: I have some ideas but not implemented yet

Answer (score 3):

I18n has support for Model and attributes' names.

In this case, the model name can be automatically translated once it is specified in the translation files.

Ex.:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    models:
      product: "produit"
    attributes:
      product:
        name: "nom"
        manufacturer: "fabricant"
```

In the case you set the flash message directly, you can use the I18n.t function and pass the action and subject parameters. Ex.:

```
flash.now[:error] = t('unauthorized', scope: 'manage.all', action: params[:action], subject: Product.model_name.human)
render 'new'
```

Maybe you will want to set some translations for actions' names and use t(params[:action], scope: 'actions') for the flash message above or simply use t('actions.new').

```
fr:
  actions:
    new: "nouveau"
```

OBS: you could use action_name (Rails 4) or controller.action_name (Rails 3) instead of params[:action].